# ¿Cómo evitar que se sobrepongan los botones con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Necesito poner 6 botones que sean *responsive* y que se alineen en un formulario *HTML*.

El problema es más bien al usar pantallas pequeñas, por que en el navegador normal salen los botones en línea horizontal sin errores, pero al reducir el tamaño de la pantalla se sobreponen unos botones en otros.

Código usando **bootstrap.css**:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
<div class="documentos">
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Resumen Ejecutivo</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Presentación de Proyecto</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Executive Summary.pdf</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BOSSTRADER.pdf</a>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes agregar las herramientas con las cuales estas trabajando. Ej Bootstrap

Comment: por ahora solo uso bottstrap, nada máas

Comment: Que se alineen cuántos por fila? Trata de dar más información sobre lo que has intentado y los errores que presentas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bienvenido a la comunidad.
La forma más sencilla de hacerlo, puede ser acoplándolos en columnas. Cada columna debe ir dentro de un row.

Es decir, podrías tener algo así como esto.
(utilizando bootstrap 4)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Y el codigo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <a href="#" class="m-3 btn btn-primary btn-block">Resumen Ejecutivo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <a href="#" class="m-3 btn btn-primary btn-block">Presentación de Proyecto</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <a href="#" class="m-3 btn btn-primary btn-block">Executive Summary.pdf</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <a href="#" class="m-3 btn btn-primary btn-block">BOSSTRADER.pdf</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nota que Bootsrap Divide las Columnas en 12, entonces al poner col-md-3, le estás diciendo que tome 3 espacios, es decir te van a caber 4 columnas de este tamaño.

Las clases con referncias "md", son para pantallas medianas y "sm" para pantallas pequeñas.
Puedes darte cuenta que si cambias el tamaño de la ventana, se adaptará entre 4 columnas, 2 columnas o 1 columna, dependiendo del ancho.

Nota también que utilizo la clase btn-block para que los botones tomen todo el ancho que se pueda, y la clase m-3 que es el margen, puedes ponerle m-2, etc... dependiendo de tu gusto.